# SwiftUI Core Data Appended Array returning Empty

Tags: arrays, swift, mapping, swiftui

I have an Entity called Lessons, which consists of:

```
@NSManaged public var timeMinutes: Double
@NSManaged public var id: UUID
@NSManaged public var lessonDescription: String
@NSManaged public var date: Dates
```

The 'date' attribute is linked with a one-to-many relationship to a separate 'Dates' entity, which consists of:

```
@NSManaged public var date: Date
```

I am now trying to display a graph that has the summed 'timeMinutes' by 'date'. This finalArray would have the following structure:

```
struct FinalArray {
    let summedMinutes : Double
    let date : Date
}
```

My code to generate (and display) this array looks as following:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUICharts

struct Test: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Lessons.allLessonsFetchRequest()) var lessons: FetchedResults<Lessons>

   var finalArray = [FinalArray]()

    init(){
        let coreDataArray = [Lessons]()
        let allKeys = Set<Date>(coreDataArray.map{$0.date.date})
        for key in allKeys {
            let sum = coreDataArray.filter({$0.date.date == key}).map({$0.timeMinutes}).reduce(0, +)
            finalArray.append(FinalArray(summedMinutes:sum, date:key))
        }
       finalArray = finalArray.sorted(by: {$0.date < $1.date})
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
               LineView(data:  finalArray.map {$0.summedMinutes}, title: "This graph returns empty").padding()
               LineView(data:  lessons.map {$0.timeMinutes}, title: "This graph works").padding()
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the finalArray returns nothing when I run this? My Core Data is not empty; the graph that displays the mapped 'timeMinutes' is populated. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

If I add a simple button to my View that adds values to FinalArray it works:

```
   Button(action: {
            self.finalArray.append(FinalArray(summedMinutes: 20, date: Date()))
                         }, label: {
                             Text("Add")
                         })
```

This would suggest that the FinalArray and the chart reading from it works, but the data can't be retrieved from Core Data somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: Comment: 
I now understand that I basically assign the structure 'Lessons' to CoreDataArray, but I don't actually load the Core Data ('lessons') into the CoreDataArray. How do I do this in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding it as an `onAppear` instead of `init`, as following:

```
   @State private var finalArray = [FinalArray]()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
               LineView(data:  finalArray.map {$0.summedMinutes}, title: "This graph returns empty").padding()
               LineView(data:  lessons.map {$0.timeMinutes}, title: "This graph works").padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
           let allKeys = Set<Date>(self.lessons{$0.date.date})
           for key in allKeys {
               let sum = self.lessons.filter({$0.date.date == key}).map({$0.timeMinutes}).reduce(0, +)
               self.finalArray.append(FinalArray(summedMinutes:sum, date:key))
           }
          self.finalArray = self.finalArray.sorted(by: {$0.date < $1.date})
       }
    }
```

Kudos to Asperi!

Answer (score 0):

sorted(by:) returns the elements of the sequence, sorted using the given predicate.
It does not sort inplace. So try this:

finalArray = finalArray.sorted(by: {$0.date < $1.date})

Comment: Thanks, this works! However, my Array is still empty. Do you have any idea why that might be?